# Why does the multiplicative order divide $|\mathbb{F}|-1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-fields

[This source](http://faculty.bard.edu/%7Ebelk/math318/CyclotomicPolynomials.pdf) describes Lagrange's theorem for finite fields (page 6). It generalizes Fermat's little theorem. In particular, it states that if $\mathbb{F}$ is a field with finitely many elements, with $|\mathbb{F}|=m$, then
$$a^{m-1}=1$$
for every $a\in\mathbb{F}\setminus\{0\}$.

To prove this, they note that $\mathbb{F}\setminus\{0\}$ has $m-1$ elements. But then, they suddenly conclude that this implies $\text{ord}_{\mathbb{F}}(a)$ divides $m-1$. The result then follows.

How is the divisibility claim reached?

Comment: Do you know [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) for the order of subgroups of a group?  Specifically here the group of nonzero elements of a finite field under the field's multiplication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathrm{ord}_{\Bbb F}(a)=|\langle a\rangle|\mid|\Bbb F\setminus\{0\}|$ for any $a\in\Bbb F\setminus\{0\}$. This is Lagrange's theorem for groups

Answer (score 1):

In a field, the nonzero elements always form a group (under multiplication).  The order of that group is of course $|\Bbb F|-1$.  The conclusion is then reached by *Lagrange's theorem*.

Indeed Fermat's little theorem then follows by application to the field $\Bbb Z_p$, for any prime $p$.